# using buffer& streams to search for string in multiple text file & also to find line number in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, stream, buffer

please help me to search a string across multiple files, I need to print the line number of that particular string with filename using buffer & streams concept in node.js.

for example:

there are 5 text files and there is " hello " string in 10 and 15th line of the 3rd file. same hello string in the 50th line of the 5th file. now I need to print line number of file name 3 with the line number of that searched string "hello"
same as for the 5th file.

help me to write this program in buffer concept in node.js

Comment: If you are using unix to run this, you could just used some of the built-in commands

Comment: im using ubuntu, and i want the program in nodejs using buffer concept to process multiple files at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const fs = require("fs");

// Start methods implementation
const beginSearch = (readStream, filePath, queries) => {
  let lineCount = 0;
  let matches = new Map();
  queries.forEach(query => matches.set(query, []));

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readStream.on("line", line => {
      lineCount++;
      for (query of matches.keys()) {
        if (searchForTerm(line, query))
          matches.set(query, [...matches.get(query), lineCount]);
      }
    });

    readStream.on("close", () => resolve({
      filePath,
      matches
    }));
  });
};
const searchForTerm = (line, query) => line.match(query);

const createLineInterfaces = filePaths =>
  filePaths.map(filePath => {
    const readStream = readline.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    return {
      filePath,
      readStream
    };
  });
// End methods implementation


// Start main function

const filesToSearch = ["sample.txt", "sample2.txt"];
const queriesToSeatch = ["hello"];
let searchProms = createLineInterfaces(filesToSearch).map(
  ({
    readStream,
    filePath
  }) =>
  beginSearch(readStream, filePath, queriesToSeatch)
);

Promise.all(searchProms).then(searchResults =>
  searchResults.forEach(result => console.log(result))
);
// End main function
```

**A little explain**

I am using the [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module to split each file into lines. *Keep in mind the whole implementation is with streams*. Then i am attaching a listener to the `line` event and I am searching each line for a specific query. The search method is a simple regexp. You could use a fuzzy search method if you want. Then the matched lines are saved in a `Map` which keys are the queries and values the arrays of `lineNumbers` that the query has found.

I am assuming that you are familiar with the `stream` concept and you know about `ES6` stuff.